# Hotlink protection in nginx not working

Tags: hotlinking

This is the system of servers that I'm building upon.

- original-website.com
- duplicate-website.com
- unallowed-duplicate-website.com

[image]

I put some content in original-website.com.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>HTML 5 Boilerplate</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>

This book is written by Zeal Vora. It's a good book. I am just writing filler content here.

        <img src="zealvorabook.jfif"></img>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now I go to both duplicate-website.com as well as unallowed-duplicate-website.com and copy the contents there with image being referred to the original-website.com.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>HTML 5 Boilerplate</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
This book is written by Zeal Vora. It's a good book. I am just writing filler content here.
        <img  src="http://original-website.com/zealvorabook.jfif"></img>
  </body>
</html>
```

Same content got pasted in unallowed-duplicate-website.com

Now, I go to add the IP to domain name mapping in each of the hosts file. Like this:

```
192.168.1.75    duplicate-website.com
192.168.1.76    original-website.com
192.168.1.74    unallowed-duplicate-website.com
```

Then, I go to `/etc/nginx/conf.d/original-website.conf`

```
#original-website.conf
server{
        listen 80;
        server_name original-website.com;
        location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
        location ~* \.(jpg|png|gif|jfif)$ {
                valid_referers none duplicate-website.com;
                if ($invalid_referer) {
                        return 403;
                                        }
                                }
    }
}
```

Now, when I go to browser and type the IP address of duplicate-website.com, I'm not seeing the image. Why?

Comment: Relying on an accurate HTTP_REFERER is not a good idea. Browsers are not required to return this and increasingly don't in multiple scenarios.